# Evaluar variable recibida con peticion al servidor con ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Buenas tardes, tengo los siguientes 3 códigos.

Mediante el codigo javascript con ajax realizó la petición y se efectúa correctamente, esta es el inicio de sesión de un usuario, en caso de ser correctos los datos te dice "Bienvenido" en caso contrario "No hay usuarios registrados con esos datos".

Mi duda sería es posible evaluar lo que te regresa el método ajax? para que en caso de que el incio de sesion sea correcta, la pagina que es el index se muestre, y en caso de ser erróneo el logueo del usuario este se mantenga en esa misma ventana de login.
Como puedo interactuar con "data" que es lo que me regresa la petición al servidor con ajax.

Por su atención, gracias.

Código javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#boton').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var1 = $('#usuario').val();
  var2 = $('#pass').val();

  $.ajax({
   url: 'Controlador/login.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {var1, var2},
   beforeSend:function(){
    console.log("Se esta procesando tu peticion");
   }
  })
  .done(function(data) {
   console.log("success");
   alert(data);
  })
  .fail(function() {
   console.log("error");
  })
  .always(function() {
   console.log("complete");
  });
 });
 

 
 $('#loguearse').click(function(event) { 
  $('#ve').load('login.html');
  $('#general').hide();  
 });
 
});
```

Código PHP

```html
<?php

 require_once('../Modelo/class.conexion.php');
 require_once('../Modelo/class.consultas.php');

 $mensaje = null;

 $usuario = $_POST['var1'];
 $pass = $_POST['var2'];

 if(strlen($usuario) > 0 && strlen($pass) > 0){
  $consultas = new Consultas();
  $mensaje = $consultas->verificarUsuario($usuario, $pass); 
 }else{
  echo "Por favor rellena ambos campos";
 }

 echo $mensaje;

?>
```

Metodo verificarUsuario

```html
public function verificarUsuario($nombre_usuario,$password_usuario){
    $modelo = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
    $sql = "select nombre_usuario, password_usuario
      from usuarios
      where nombre_usuario = :nombre_usuario 
      and password_usuario = :password_usuario";
    $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);    
    $statement->bindParam(':nombre_usuario', $nombre_usuario);
    $statement->bindParam(':password_usuario', $password_usuario);
    if(!$statement){
     return "No hay usuario registrado con esos datos";
    }else{
     $statement->execute();
     if($statement->rowCount() > 0){       
      return "Bienvenido";
     }else{
      return "no hay usuarios con registrados con esos datos";
     } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu variable data es la que trae la respuesta del server, de hecho aqui traes esa informacion:

```
.done(function(data) {
            console.log("success");
            alert(data);
        })
```

Por ejemplo podrias hacer :

```
.done(function(data) {
            if (data == "Bienvenido")
                document.location.href = "index.php";
            else 
                alert(data);
        })
```

Lo que yo recomendaria es generar una respuesta mas elaborada desde el server, que puedas regresar un JSON con un Estatus y un Mensaje o algo asi.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por comentar, efectivamente la variable "data" es lo que me trae la peticion que realizé al servidor, mas sin embargo modifique un poco el metodo verificarUsuario, que tengo posteado aqui para que me regrese un 1 en caso de que el login sea correcto o un 0 en caso contrario, luego en la parte de "done" realizo un if de que si data es un 1 (se efectue correctamente el ingreso del usuario) entonces se cargue el index, mas sin embargo, no me funciona, mi problema esta interactuar con esa variable data. Intentaré lo que me mencionas, gracias.

Comment: Por que no te funciona ? No trae el valor ?

Comment: quité lo que te habia mencionado, de que regresara 0 ó 1 y lo dejé como lo puse aqui, y solo puse ese if que mencionaste arriba y funcionó correctamente, me estoy iniciando con desarrollo web, y  de repente me complico con cosas sumamente sencillas, jaja, muchas gracias.

Comment: Super! Dale respuesta aceptada va? Porfas!!